# MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_lapack.dylib

Tags: python, ipython, enthought, canopy, intel-mkl

What does this error mean? It seems that I can not open python in IPython because I haven't got MKL?

```
MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_lapack.dylib
```

This error occurs in the terminal window when I return `ipython notebook`

When executing my code, the plt.show() attempts to open python but python then crashes (that crazy blue/yellow rocket flashes then dies on the dock on my mac!).

The IPython error that I get is:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Comment: what are the outputs of `which ipython` and also of `env` in Terminal, and of `sys.path` at the ipython prompt?

Comment: I've also encountered this problem in a sudden, `cannot load libmkl_mc.so or libmkl_def.so`